# Python - Behave - Two different steps with the same name

Tags: python-2.7, python-behave

I'm running my python tests with Behave

What i want to do is implement the same step, e.g "UserA calls UserB" in diffrent step files and to point the test to the correct step teach time.

For example:

The .feature file content:

```
Scenario: User A calls User B
  Given UserA calls UserB
```

then, in the step folder, i'll have a .py file that will contain:

```
@given('UserA calls UserB')
def step_impl(context):
   print('A call is being made')
```

And another step .py file that will contain:

```
@given('UserA calls UserB')
def step_impl(context):
   print('A call is being made in another method')
```

I want to have control over which one of these steps will be executed.
Is there a clean way to do that?

Comment: can you show a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Comment: @NathanMcCoy I've added a simple example to explain the idea of what i want to do

Comment: It is all structured nicely so you don't confuse stuff. Why do you want this? What is the difference? a) rewrite your step so it can perform the call the right way in both situation. or b) change the step name because it really is a different step.

Comment: You could use tags. For example, when the scenario is tagged with `@UI`, the step could exercise the UI with selenium but when it is tagged with `@Integration` then it could work on a lower level, avoiding the UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer after asking in the behave Github repository:

The best way to differentiate steps is to use test stages.

Example:

If i want to write the same steps with different implementation using the same .feature file i can open two directories:

```
dev_steps/
integration_steps/
```

and point to each of them in the behave command using stage:

```
behave --stage=dev
```

or

```
behave --stage=integration
```